# Fill in a form's default values?

Tags: laravel

I use the same HTML for my form, there is two modes, add and edit. In edit mode the values are filled in.

```
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="{{ $data->title }}">
```

The above errors when $data does not exist, so I:

```
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="{{ $data->title or '' }}">
```

I was just wondering is there a better way to do this? So that in add mode no value appears.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to approach this is to use the FormBuilder provided by Laravel. That way you can use Form Model Binding to automatically populate your form. To split the create and edit form, I usually create a _form.blade.php file which contains my form. Then, I create two views, a create.blade.php and edit.blade.php. In these views I put something like this:

```
// From create.blade.php

{{ Form::open([ 'route' => 'resource_name.store', 'method' => 'POST' ]) }}
    @include('_form')
{{ Form::close() }}



// From edit.blade.php
{{ Form::model($data, [ 'route' => 'resource_name.update', 'method' => 'PUT' ]) }}
    @include('_form')
{{ Form::close() }}



// From _form.blade.php
{{ Form::text('title', null, [ 'placeholder' => 'Title' ]) }}
```

*Note: I am putting an underscore before the view name to 'mark' it as a partial, just a convention I adopted*

When using this method, you can have the re-use the same form for both create and edit, which keeps it easy to maintain.

By using the Form::model() method for the edit form, Laravel will automatically bind the provided model (in your case the $data variable) to the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

{{ $data->title }} you could use an  If condition to achieve this have used in several development techniques.

```
<?php if (empty($name)) {
echo ''
}
else {
echo '$data->title';
```

?>